# How not to show author's name when sharing blogposts on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

(I'm a WP-Beginner and have to work on a WP-Blog someone else build & heavily modified, so please bear with me)

On my WP-blog, I'm not showing the authors name on individual posts (or anywhere else). I'm using the following code in my single.php to let readers share posts on Facebook:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&t=<?php the_title(); ?>" 
target="_blank" 
title="share this post on Facebook"> 
<div class="fb_button">
</div>
</a>
```

this works great; however inside this shared information the author's name shows up. My clients don't want that. Is there any way to only share the actual content of the post, but not its author?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI, it's "Penske" :) See http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=penske%20file

Comment: On your blog, does the author's name show up in the browser window title when you view an individual blog post?

Comment: Ben, no it doesn't